# ASP.NET: How to crash graciously using web.config setting?

Tags: .net, asp.net, deployment, error-handling, web-config

Is there a way to display a benign error page (using some settings in web.config) when an asp.net app crashes ?

I have an app whose database is updated regularly. If the database is updated while a user is using the app, frequently the app crashes. If the app's webpage is refreshed then everything is OK again.

How best to handle a situation like this? Is there a way to direct all crashes to a webpage that tells the user to just refresh? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can define and turn on custom error pages.

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~\ErrorPages\GenericError.htm">
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="~\ErrorPages\NoAccess.htm" />
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~\ErrorPages\PageNotFound.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

Set the `mode` to `On` for all requests or `RemoteOnly` to enable custom errors only on remote requests. Then define as many error pages as you need for the various errors.

---

While you are updating your application, you might consider placing an `app_offline.htm` file in the root of your web app. If that file is present it is shown for all incoming requests. See http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/09/442332.aspx for more info.

Answer (score 3):

The best thing is whenever you want to make any changes on a live website/Database, is to take down the website by putting an `app_offline.htm` file in the application folder. The user should not see your application if it crashes.

Comment: Be careful with this to make sure you have 512+ bytes of content - see: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/09/442332.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You could also trap the errors in your global.asax which has a handler for errors, interrogate the error there (using something like Exception ex = Server.GetLastError()) and if it meets the criteria for whatever you're looking for, redirect them to whatever you want.